# Twilio unable to delete a sms command watever the status of the command

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The documentation of twilio say you can delete a command or a sms command if the status is sent or failed. But there is now explanation for the procedure.

I tried to delete by a call api to DELETE [https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Commands/{sid}..](https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Commands/%7Bsid%7D..).

The command didn't work.

here the documentation links

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/command-resource#deleting-commands
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/smscommand-resource#deleting-commands

What is the way to delete some commands?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here, I'm checking this with the team and will report back when I find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It turns out this was a mistake in the documentation. There is not a `DELETE` method for Commands or SmsCommands and that is why your attempt failed and why there are not methods for it in the Twilio helper libraries.

We are updating the docs now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: So this means even whatsapp deleting sent sms doesnt work as welll because we are just getting errors (update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status) using flask

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking there @lewismachilika, but your best bet is to ask a new question with all the context around your problem, or raise this with Twilio support.